# Import Bookmarks in Firefox from Windows to Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox

I have windows 7 64 bit on my laptop and have just installed ubuntu 14.04. Is there a way to import my bookmarks from my windows firefox and integrate them into my ubuntu firefox web browser? I could not find anyway to import bookmarks from windows I have no other details available.

Comment: Why all upper cases?

Comment: @kostandinangjellari please, don't forget editing the tags.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Firefox in Windows:
2. Bookmarks - Show All Bookmarks - Import and Backup - Export Backup to HTML
3. Choose a path and save html
4. Open Firefox in Ubuntu
5. Bookmarks - Show All Bookmarks - Import and Backup - Import Backup from HTML
6. Choose the path you saved html from windows
7. Open.

---

You have successfully imported your bookmarks from windows.

Comment: This was a very good answer and works just as you said I hope this post helps others to.